# CSS Transition on image not working

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, image, transition

On the top of my website i've got a gallery, when you scroll down the page i want the gallery to be displayed in a smaller version.

**big version:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fniUS.png]

**small version:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VfiF.png]

I made this with jQuery, when you scroll 300px (gallery initial height) you get the small one of around 100px height.

I've set some transitions on that:

Initial :

```
#gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 305px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:white;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
#gallery img {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
```

Scrolled :

```
#fixed_gallery {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  z-index: 53 !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  background-color:white;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

#fixed_gallery img {
  height: 95px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  padding: 2px !important;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
```

I've got the same code for the navigation arrows and they do scale with a transition.. im kinda lost with this :\ !

How do I get this transition to work? So when the gallery goes to small version, i want that the image goes smaller with a nice transition.

Reference url : http://ehad.mediaheads.nl/blog/ & http://jsfiddle.net/fzjqyhcw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css transition on your images is not working because you don't actually resize the images.

Try adding a class (instead of switching the parent's id) so that you can do something like this:

```
#gallery {
   ...
   position: relative;
}

#gallery img {
   ...
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

#gallery.fixed-gallery {
   ....
   position: fixed;
}

#gallery.fixed-gallery img {
   ....
   height: 95px;
}
```

Comment: It actually does, if you post a jsFiddle example of your current result I could probably help you out.

Comment: I think it is because the images are nested in the div, and get loaded again when it switches position or something, could this be the case? And how could i fix this?

Comment: Not sure why, but somehow it does not work if `#gallery` has a `display: inline-block;` see  http://jsfiddle.net/fzjqyhcw/3/

Comment: Awesome man! it works indeed. Good thing the display didn't even do anything haha, put it as answer so i can vote you.